# how call function after click href to another link loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hello i need some function going to run after a link before another page.

for example.

this is main.html

```
<div>
<a href="another.html" onclick="linkPopup()" target="_blank" title="popup"></a>
</div>
```

> and when click  tag.

another.html loaded and open popup inside in function exist already in another.html

another.html
open popup!

like this.

Comment: Hi your example isn't very clear partyly due to the grammar but mostly due to the example code you've posted. You can get more answers by posting a more complete question. If you call a modal in the page that modal has to be there already, to call another page you'd need to use ajax to grab that content or an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use localStorage for this functionality. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Page current.html

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="linkPopup()" title="popup"> Another Page </a>
<script>
  function linkPopup(){
    localStorage.setItem('popup',true)
    window.location.href = "another.html";
  }
</script>
```

Page another.html

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady',function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('popup')==true){
     // Script for open the popup
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, Change your html like this way

```
<a href="#" onclick="linkPopup()" title="popup"> Another Page </a>
```

Then define you function like this way

```
function linkPopup() {
    // do your function task here
    alert("Alert");

    // go to the another page
    window.location.href = "another.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to call function before goes to another.html , to achieve this , very simple is

remove link from anchor and location.href in function

```
function linkPopup()
{
   //some code here and last line is below,
   location.href = 'another.html';
}
```